# Use the fields of a struct while also using its address

Tags: c++

```
struct nod {
    std::pair<int, int> matrixPos;
    nod *anteriorNode;

    nod(std::pair<int, int> matrixPos)
    {
        matrixPos = matrixPos;
        anteriorNode = nullptr;
    } //this is for the first node

    nod(std::pair<int, int> matrixPos, nod* anteriorNode)
    {
        matrixPos = matrixPos;
        anteriorNode = anteriorNode;
    }
};

void expandNode(std::queue<nod> &coada, int **matrice, nod& nodToExpand)
{
    if (matrice[nodToExpand.matrixPos.first-1][nodToExpand.matrixPos.second] == 0)
    {
        nod newNode = nod(std::pair<int, int>(nodToExpand.matrixPos.first - 1, nodToExpand.matrixPos.second), nodToExpand);
    }
}
```

I have some nodes that I need to link together (so I know which is the parent of each node) while also accessing their values.

I need to acess their matrixPos fields for the values needed in the if statement, while I also need
their address for the field 'anteriorNode'.

How can I do this and what is the most efficient way?

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me, are you asking "How can I get a pointer to `nodToExpand` from within the `expandNode` function"? If that's the case, you can just do `&nodToExpand`.

Comment: @Frank yes. That's what I was asking, I don't know how I could've missed such a basic thing lol. Thanks - you can add it as an answer, I'll accept it asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is obtain a pointer to `nodToExpand` from within the `expandNode` function, you can do so by getting its address. References can be used as if they where the referred object itself, that's their whole deal.

All you need is a good old `&nodToExpand`.